# Menu with Submenu not working

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm beginning on AS3, very beginning, I saw lot of tutorials, but it seems I am hitting a wall now.

My project:

- I've got a principal menu (`menu`) having a submenu (`menu_seul`) containing three buttons (`btn_check`, `btn_date` and `btn_com`).
- On click, a different text should appear. 
  I put in three different frames of `menu_seul` (As the 1 as empty one).

Is there a way to simplify it as I have just one EventListener calling... 
If not, why does my code not work ?

Thanks for your help!

```
menu.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, menu_on, false, 0, true);
menu.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OUT, menu_out, false, 0, true);

btn_com.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, btn_com_on, false, 0, true);
btn_com.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OUT, btn_com_out, false, 0, true);
btn_date.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, btn_date_on, false, 0, true);
btn_date.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OUT, btn_date_out, false, 0, true);
btn_check.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, btn_check_on, false, 0, true);
btn_check.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OUT, btn_check_out, false, 0, true);

function menu_on(event:MouseEvent):void{
menu.gotoAndPlay(2);
}

function menu_out(event:MouseEvent):void{
menu.gotoAndPlay(25);
}

function btn_com_on(event:MouseEvent):void{
menu_seul.gotoAndPlay(2);
}

function btn_com_out(event:MouseEvent):void{
menu.gotoAndPlay(1);
}

function btn_date_on(event:MouseEvent):void{
menu_seul.gotoAndPlay(3);
}

function btn_date_out(event:MouseEvent):void{
menu.gotoAndPlay(1);
}

function btn_check_on(event:MouseEvent):void{
menu_seul.gotoAndPlay(4);
}

function btn_check_out(event:MouseEvent):void{
menu.gotoAndPlay(1);
}
```

Thanks again !

Comment: I don't think the current one is working because your on/out functions are targeting different things. For example, btn date on targets menu_seul, yet btn date off targets just menu

Comment: New problems born !
Now I'm trying with a general hover function... I'l tell you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it.
Actually, my code wasn't so wrong, this is it now :

```
menu.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, menu_on, false, 0, true);
menu.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OUT, menu_out, false, 0, true);

btn_com.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, btn_com_on, false, 0, true);
btn_com.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OUT, btn_com_out, false, 0, true);
btn_date.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, btn_date_on, false, 0, true);
btn_date.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OUT, btn_date_out, false, 0, true);
btn_check.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, btn_check_on, false, 0, true);
btn_check.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OUT, btn_check_out, false, 0, true);

function menu_on(event:MouseEvent):void{
menu.gotoAndPlay(2);
}

function menu_out(event:MouseEvent):void{
menu.gotoAndPlay(25);
}

function btn_com_on(event:MouseEvent):void{
menu_seul.gotoAndPlay(2);
}

function btn_com_out(event:MouseEvent):void{
menu_seul.gotoAndPlay(1);
}

function btn_date_on(event:MouseEvent):void{
menu_seul.gotoAndPlay(3);
}

function btn_date_out(event:MouseEvent):void{
menu_seul.gotoAndPlay(1);
}

function btn_check_on(event:MouseEvent):void{
menu_seul.gotoAndPlay(4);
}

function btn_check_out(event:MouseEvent):void{
menu_seul.gotoAndPlay(1);
}
```

It was just my objects, I had just to name them differently between object, occurence and AS exportable name !
So, Flash said to me they weren't constant (Class) !

Thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

Create a function to add a function for a button action:

```
function addAction(target:*, event:String, action:Function, params:Array) {
    target.addEventListener(event, function (event:Event) { action(params); });
}
```

Then, add the action for each event for each button:

```
addAction(menu, MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, menu.gotoAndPlay, [2]);
addAction(menu, MouseEvent.ROLL_OUT, menu.gotoAndPlay, [25]);
addAction(btn_com, MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, menu_seul.gotoAndPlay, [2]);
addAction(btn_com, MouseEvent.ROLL_OUT, menu.gotoAndPlay, [1]);
...
```

If you what, you can create an array to register all buttons and its actions:

```
var buttons:Array = [
    {button:menu, overAction:menu.gotoAndPlay, overActionParams:[2], outAction:menu.gotoAndPlay, outActionParams:[25]},
    {button:btn_com, overAction:menu_seul.gotoAndPlay, overActionParams:[2], outAction:menu.gotoAndPlay, outActionParams:[1]},
    {button:btn_date, overAction:menu_seul.gotoAndPlay, overActionParams:[3], outAction:menu.gotoAndPlay, outActionParams:[1]},
    {button:btn_check, overAction:menu_seul.gotoAndPlay, overActionParams:[4], outAction:menu.gotoAndPlay, outActionParams:[1]}
];

for each (var item:Object in buttons)
{
    addAction(item.button, MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, item.overAction, item.overActionParams);
    addAction(item.button, MouseEvent.ROLL_OUT, item.outAction, item.outActionParams);
}
```

That's all!!

Comment: I did it just for menu, to try, and I just get a '1046: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant:menu.' Object's name, occurence name, and AS exportable name are menu... I don't what to tell him... And, of course it's not a constant 'cause it's a movie clip on the way to move on hover... Whatever, thank you a lot for patience and answer fenixkim ! It will certainly help me to undersand AS3 :)